# Can anybody write the select query for this issue?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I havetwo Tables namely mit_follow & mit_tweets

**In mit_follow table structure :**

```
Id    UserName            followers          Following

1     dobriyalji          manish             Sachin
2     dobriyalji          karthik            parul
```

**In mit_tweets table structure :**

```
Id        UserName          tweets

1         dobriyalji        hi everybody
2         manish            hello all m karthik
```

i wanna write the select query for this ..

if i login using username dobriyalji .... and post tweets in mit_tweets table then dobriyalji and all of his followers can view their msgs and all the followers msgs will be viewed by dobriyalji...i m displaying the mit_tweets table using gridview in webform....

and if any new member login to their account and  post tweets then in gridview only new member msg will display ...

can any body write the select query for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your mit_follow table. Your followers and Following columns don't really make sense. Surely the table should look more like:

```
id user            user_followed
** *************** ******************
1  dobriyalji      Sachin
2  dobriyalji      parul
3  manish          dobriyalji      
4  karthik         dobriyalji
```

This would be much easier to query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mit_tweets.* 
FROM mit_tweets 
WHERE username = 'dobriyalji' 

UNION 

SELECT t2.* 
FROM mit_tweets 
    INNER JOIN mit_follow ON mit_tweets.Username = mit_follow.Username 
    INNER JOIN mit_tweets t2 ON mit_follow.following = t2.Username 
WHERE mit_tweets.username = 'dobriyalji'
```

Is that what you mean?

Or maybe this:

```
select *
from mit_tweets
where Username = 'dobryialji' 
or username in ( select mit_follow.followers from mit_follow where mit_follow.username = mit_tweets.username )
```

This doesnt' make sense to me.  If I'm dobryialji, then I want to see my own tweets, plus the tweets of the people I follow.  If that is true, then change mit_follow.followers to mit_follow.following.

Comment: i dont knwo how to write the sql select quuery ... but what i  want is mentioned in above question ... let me check this

Comment: have u wite this query according to my question Matt

Comment: matt .... the problem with this query ..if dobriyalji write any msg then the message will not display to their followers ..

Comment: both the queries displays same ..i want ... if the person1 follow person2 then the messages displayed in person1 and person2 will be same either the person login to their account and person2 login to their account ...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Edit your question and put more data in there, then also write out exactly the rows you would expect to be returned.  Until you do that, then I can't help you any further.